# Why character's face automatically converts into green in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, scenekit, maya, texture-mapping

I am using Autodesk Maya for creating models and animations of this character. This character appears and animates perfectly on all other platforms like Unity, 3dsMax, etc. but when I import `.dae` file in Xcode the face of the character appears green and not showing the perfect texture.

[image: /this image have a view of a green face issue/]

This model has perfect UV's on the face, other faces are used as blend shapes those shows perfect texture. UV's of the main face which appears green.

[image: /this image have a UV coordinate info of face/]

The face appears in Unity

[image: /model appearance in unity/]

What changes are required to change green color appearance of face to normal?

Answer (score 0):

If any Maya material appears as green surface in SceneKit, you should delete a UV-mapped texture in Maya (check whether you're using Lambert, Blinn or Phong shader) and re-apply UV-mapped texture from scratch.

Green surface usually means a 3D object doesn't have a shading group assigned, or shader is somewhat corrupted, or error appears during import.

If you can't reassign a UV-mapped texture in Maya, try to assign this texture in SceneKit's `Scenegraph`. For that select a head and using ***Diffuse*** slot in `Material Inspector` choose a texture from a drop-down menu (the best image format in this case is `.jpg` on `.png`).

P.S.

I've found that your model was locked in Maya. Check `ChannelBox` and `AttributeEditor`.

Comment: @DayDreamer, have you achieved a result in this matter?  If not, share your model via file sharing service, like https://dropmefiles.com. I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi, Andy Fedoroff
thanks for your reply. I tried all solutions you suggested but the face still appears green,
Here I am sharing the images and clips of my settings so you can get the idea.

Comment: 1. image for without material
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KaEHEoV_FNpQnteOIiuadk4w0Kqq4392/view?usp=sharing

2. Image for a model with material
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lJx-AsC8lyiyBk32idnPq0WH9DmROXLr/view?usp=sharing

3. video clip for PBR shader created in Xcode SceneKit
https://drive.google.com/file/d/170zlijU8XUAVXd2zVBmr75nEt1FmIIZf/view?usp=sharing

4. create new material of blinn from scratch in maya and apply to face
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1waPnTnXJtO3XnJI-1An9HrDo86Wfl7Gt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You've shared pictures and video))). I said about model...

Comment: Share just a green head. I do not need a whole model.

Comment: I had uploaded it on the given link. Inform me if you still didn't get it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tD1ErSocxuHQgC8du2FPp8x1pS5rV3LG/view?usp=sharing

try this link

previous one was on this
https://dropmefiles.com/

Comment: I've found an issue. Your geometry (green head) is locked. I can't choose it in `Scene graph`. Check this out in Maya.

Comment: Check `Channel Box` and `Attribute Editor`.

Comment: Thanks, andy 
I have unlocked the model using this way
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bfGwRLHzlxwWIl4ZjAQ7LlTOb1UjZvab/view?usp=sharing

You can check in your Scene graph here is link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZWsSNZRQXojVuIVOB-Zk7dybR38P4QEG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234830/discussion-between-day-dreamer-and-andy-fedoroff).

Comment: Sorry I can't continue the discussion in chat. I'm busy.

Comment: I tested v2 model. The head is still blocked (locked). I cannot select it in Scene graph. It's 100% Maya's issue...